# Quiet Diodes at Audio Frequencies

Tags: audio

I am using diodes to bias tubes for the input stage of an audio circuit.  They will hold the cathode off ground by their forward voltage (Vf).  Current will probably fall between 1 and 2 mA, and the voltage will be set by the diode's Vf.  I am aiming for .8V-1.6V total, and I can have diodes in series to obtain the right bias voltage (thought multiple junctions tend to raise the noise level).  Peak-to-peak AC will be in the 250mV range.

I would like to know if anyone is aware of low noise, low distortion diodes that will have minimal effect on the audio signal passing through them.  I've experimented with several types, Schottkeys, 4007, 914, etc.  The Schottkey rectifier diodes and the 4007s are best so far.  Of course, at 1mA, their rated Vf is quite different from the specs that are usually published.  Only the most complete spec sheets show Vf below 10mA or so.  The Cree 6010s (rectifiers) came in at .8V and the 4007s came in at .5V.

I realize that most people don't use diodes in this application, so information has been hard to come by.

[image: Diode schematic]

imagine a triode tube, the anode is fed 155V through a 75K plate resistor, the grid is fed from the output of a microphone capsule and has 200Megs to ground. The cathode has two 4007 diodes in series to ground. Signal is taken from the anode, through a capacitor to the an output transformer. This results in 1V of bias at at the cathode, 75V on the anode, and 1.5mA of current flowing through the tube. The diodes each provide .5V of the total bias voltage and are, themselves, biased by the 1.5mA of current. The diodes never see negative voltage

Comment: Worth re-examining your reason for wanting to avoid traditional self-biasing, with a resistor in the cathode circuit.

Comment: I normally refuse to draw schematics for the people that ask a question – I feel it's the job of whoever asks to make their point clear, and that includes a schematic. I made an exception here – please check whether the schematic is what you've meant. If it is not, you **must** add your own

Comment: @Marcus Müller: I guess the 200MOhm at input is not a resistor as component but the inherently given resistance between gate and GND. I've never seen a 200MOhm resistor.

Comment: @Curd was my guess, too. I see 200 MΩ all over the place – for example, this 10cm piece of relatively dry wood here… anyway, the point is to show that the mic voltage floats comfortably around ground

Comment: @Terry Setter: I still don't understand **why** you want to apply the bias voltage. Can you explain?

Comment: @Marcus Müller: the piece of wood may have 200MOhm resist**ance** (physical property) but I wouldn't call it a resist**or** (component) or draw it in  the schematic.

Comment: @Curd, true, but this schematic can't stand alone, anyway. I really hope OP picks this up and produces a schematic of his own! Re: why bias? because [tube triodes need negative Ug - Uk to set the operating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:TriodeECC83Characteristic1.png).

Comment: Marcus - you have the schematic exactly and I thank you very much for taking your time to add it.  The 200M grid resistor

Comment: @MarcusMüller - you have the schematic exactly and I thank you very much for taking your time to add it.  The 200M grid resistor works well with the extremely high impedance, roughly 80pF microphone capsules.  60M to 1G grid resistors are in common usage for tube microphones.  Tube overload characteristics are so desirable that we are still using them in many of the best microphone designs.  The diodes allow me to avoid using a resistor -gain loss and noise increase- or a bypass cap -smearing of time constants that is audible.  Thus, my search for a Hi-Fi diode with Vf of .5-1V.

Comment: @BrianDrummond - There are several ways that tube microphones have been biased and each scheme has a sonic "signature".  Many of the older classics used one of three types: negative voltage applied to the grid (fixed bias), lifting the cathode with a resistor and optional bypass cap (self-bias), and adding positive voltage to the cathode above a small resistor to ground.  I am attempting to approximate the sound one of the great mics in history (the Neumann U47), which used positive voltage at the cathode in conjunction with a small Rk.  Diodes get me very close and avoid PS noise issues.

Comment: @TerrySetter notice how you're contradicting yourself – you want "low noise, no distortion", but also "sonic "signature"". The fact that, from an signal processing point of view, tube amplifiers are *not* very good amplifiers for weak signals is what makes your signature

Comment: @MarcusMüller  Tubes in microphones are more important for their impedance converting function than for amplification.  I need low noise/distortion in the diodes, because I want the "sonic signature" to come from other parts of the circuit (particular tube, transformer, and capacitors).  The diodes are only there to set the operating level of the tube - which, itself, contributes to the sonic signature.  There is a reason that it's easy to find $10K tube mics, but hard to find a $4K transistor mics.  Getting it all right is difficult, but the sound is fantastic!

Answer (score 1):

Diodes, pretty much by definition, are non-linear components, which means that they *always* distort your signal. The trick is to operate them within a range small enough to make the nonlinearity so small that you cannot measure it.

The point of why people use diodes in biasing is that if you pick a saturated operating point, the voltage across the  diode will not depend much on the current passing through it. That's pretty much the opposite of what you want – you'd fix the gate at \$V_{cat} + V_F\$, and that's it. All signal that you apply should basically be "swallowed" by the diode.

The diode types you mention are *old* to *positively ancient*. The 400x series are rectifier diodes, ie. optimized to be nonlinear. The 914 is the predecessor of the already practically obsolete 1N4148 series – seriously, where would one even dig up such old components?

Old diode types are *not* preferable if you want low noise operation.

Comment: Thanks for your input, Marcus.  I was surprised to see that the rectifier diodes outperformed the signal diodes, and you are quite right, I need to try MODERN signal diodes (and maybe rectifier diodes as well).  The thicker coatings of the higher current models yield higher Vf, and that has been helpful.  Any recommendations as to maker/number to try?

Comment: as I tried to explain, it's probably a bad idea to use diodes for exactly this, since their purpose is the opposite of what you're doing, unless you're using a more advanced biasing than your question let's assume – you should probably add a schematic that explains what you're doing. If I knew what your schematic looks like, I could make more detailed recommendations.

Comment: and you're mistaken: The forward voltage of a diode has nothing to do with the thickness of a coating - it's a physical function of the doting and the involved semiconductors.

Comment: Could you say more about what makes "modern" diodes less noisy than "obsolete" ones like the 4148? I haven't heard of this.

Comment: Regarding forward voltage being related to "thicker coatings", Cree's website describes forward voltage drop in diodes as increasing with higher current models due to the greater thickness of doping that is necessary to accommodate higher current through them.

Comment: No schematic, but imagine a triode tube, the anode is fed 155V through a 75K plate resistor, the grid is fed from the output of a microphone capsule and has 200Megs to ground.  The cathode has two 4007 diodes in series to ground.  Signal is taken from the anode, through a capacitor to the an output transformer.  This results in 1V of bias at at the cathode, 75V on the anode, and 1.5mA of current flowing through the tube.  The diodes each provide .5V of the total bias voltage and are, themselves, biased by the 1.5mA of current.  The diodes never see negative voltage.  I hope this helps.

Comment: @TerrySetter this really can't work out without a schematic. I drew what I understood that you explained and added that your original question. I hop it's what you've meant – If it's not, replace it yourself. Really, such a complex question makes no sense without the author of the question offering a schematic

Comment: @BrianDrummond very sorry, I must have forgotten to answer; so: forward-biased diodes exhibit two kinds of noise; a) Johnsson-Nyquist Thermal noise, as everything else; power of that is proportional to \$\Re\{Z\}\$ of the impedance at working point, b) 1/f noise of carriers filling "traps", ie. contaminations, usually at the surface of the semiconductor, and then randomly relax after a time (hence the frequency dependency). Contaminiations were successfully reduced quite a bit since JEDEC standardiced 1Nxxxx.

Comment: If noise at the bias voltage is a problem, why not just filter it out, i.e. add parallel capacitor(s)?

Comment: I'd have to sit back and write down a couple of differential equations, @Curd , but: The anode current is OP's output signal. Anode is a function of grid-kathode and anode-kathode voltage. With the diodes in place, kathode potential (and hence, grid-kathode voltage) depend *exponentially* on the kathode current (and hence, the anode current). That probably leads to logarithmic amplifier behaviour. That leads to distortion in frequency domain – you get frequency components where there weren't any in the original signal.

Comment: @Curd now add the potential for oscillation of energy between junction capacitance and your capacitor to that equation. It means that if you manage, by having a high Ia for some time, to charge the capacitor, you suddenly get a *lower* amplification the instants after, until the cap is discharged again. I think you'd be killing noise at a high linearity cost.

Comment: @Marcus Müller: the other way round: kathode current depends exponentially on kathode potential. I.e. kathode potential depens logarithmically on Kathode current. So above Vf potential varies very little with current (log(x) gets flatter and flatter with increasing x). In any case a capacitor would even reduce the (already little) dependency.

Comment: @Curd I finally managed to successfully confuse myself :) 11:16am, not that bad for a weekday.

Comment: All - I have a number of diodes on order and will report back when I've measured their performance in my circuit.  Thanks for all the input to date.

Comment: In my application (biasing a small signal tube), and from about sixteen diode types that I tested for noise performance, the UF4007 and BA159 were the quietest. The reason to choose one over the other would be that two 4007s set the bias at 1V, and two BA159s set it at 1.1V. The mic I am trying to clone, for lack of a better word, had its bias at 1.1V.  I realize that it will end up with a different type of tube than was in the original, but if there aren't noticeable differences in the performance of the tube I ultimately use at 1V versus 1.1V, I'll go with the BA159s for sheer nostalgia.

Comment: Tests included UFs, HexFREDS, Schottkys, and even a PIN, which was the absolute worst in the bunch. The difference between the best and the worst of these diodes' performance was about 3.5dB.

If I had only needed .8V of bias, a single Cree SiC diode would get ever-so-slightly better noise performance due to having only one junction.

I'll do distortion measurements when the tube is selected. Then, I'll take one more pass with the UF4007s and possibly one or two others (UF/SR, etc.) and see if there are any improvements that would outweigh having the lowest noise and/or small packaging.